# Using numpy universal function in Pyomo Objective

Tags: numpy, pyomo

I have trouble using numpy functions (for example the numpy ufunc `sqrt`) in a Pyomo `Objective`.

Take the following dummy model:

```py
simple_model_1 = ConcreteModel()
simple_model_1.x = Var(domain=PositiveReals)
def simple_rule_1(m):
    return np.sqrt(m.x)
simple_model_1.obj = Objective(rule=simple_rule_1)
```

This fails with the following error:

> TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type NoneType which has no callable sqrt method

Of course, in this example, I can avoid the problem by not using Numpy. For example:

```
simple_model_2 = ConcreteModel()
simple_model_2.x = Var(domain=PositiveReals)
def simple_rule_2(m):
    return m.x**0.5
simple_model_2.obj = Objective(rule=simple_rule_2)
```

works just fine.

There are instances, though, where numpy is what I want to use. Is there a restriction to using numpy functions in pyomo objective functions? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`np.sqrt` working with a numeric numpy array uses fast compiled computation.  But if given something else it will first do `np.array(m.x)`.

If that produces an object `dtype` array, it will iterate and attempt to use the `sqrt` method of that object.

The error tells us that `m.x` is `None` or contains `None` values.  Obviously `None.sqrt()` does not work.

Comment: Thanks, it is useful to see how numpy reacts when not passed an array. I'll wait to see if someone from the Pyomo community would deal with this then. I doubt I'm the first to use numpy in a Pyomo model component expression.